# fmincon won't satisfy non linear constraints

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I've read a paper about soft color segmentation with an energy function which has to be optimized with regard to some constraints. To wrap soft color segmentation up. You define an amount of layers, each representing some color (with mean and variation). Each pixel within those layer has an rgb color and alpha value.

As said, the paper introduces an energy function, which has to be optimized in regard to the alpha value and color value in each layer:

F_s = \sum_i \alpha_i D_i(\mathbf{u_i}) + \sigma  \left( \frac{\sum_i \alpha_i}{\sum_i \alpha_i^2} - 1 \right )

```
function obj = costFunction(x, rows, columns, mean)
 [alphaLayers, layerColors] = unfoldFeatures(x, rows, columns, size(mean, 1));

 sigma = 10;

 [dimModel, ~] = size(mean);

 distance = layerColors - reshape(mean, 1, 1, 3, dimModel);

 unmixingEnergy = ( alphaLayers .* (sqrt( sum((distance.^2), 3))) );
 unmixingEnergy = sum( unmixingEnergy(:) )  ;
 sparsityTerm =  sigma * ( (sum(alphaLayers(:)) / (sum(alphaLayers(:) .^2))) - 1 );

 obj = unmixingEnergy + sparsityTerm;
end
```

The constraints are simple, the sum of the alpha values for each pixel has to be 1 and combining each layer has to reproduce the original image.

```
function [C, Ceq]= equalityConstrains(x, rows, columns, dimModel, originalPicture)
[alphaLayer, layerColors] = unfoldFeatures(x, rows, columns, dimModel);
  alphaConstraint = (sum(alphaLayer, 3) - 1);
  temp = zeros(size(originalPicture), 'double');
  for i = 1:dimModel
     temp = temp + layerColors(:, :, :, i) .* alphaLayer(:, :, i);
  end
  colorConstraint = abs(temp(:) - originalPicture(:)) * -1;
  %colorConstraint = colorConstraint) * -1; %fmincon needs the constraint to be zero or negative
  Ceq  = [ (alphaConstraint(:));    
         (colorConstraint(:))      
        ];  
   C = [];
end
```

I use fmincon as an optimizer, which is invoked as follows:

```
x0 = foldFeature(alphaLayer, layerColors);
phi = @(x) costFunction(x, r, c , double((mean)));
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb = zeros(1, length(x0), 'double') - eps;
ub = ones(1, length(x0), 'double') + eps;
nonlcon = @(x)equalityConstrains(x, r, c, m, uniqueImage);
[x, fval, exitflag, lambda] = fmincon(phi, x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, nonlcon, options);
```

My problem at this point is that while the optimizer reduces the cost function for the first 2 - 6 iterations, the constraints are not met. After iteration 6 the cost are increasing and the constraints are still violated.
Is this the wrong approach or do I need to use another algortihm? I tried sqp and interior-point. My picture get's downscaled to 100 to 100 pixels. The constraints of the inital values are okay. The folding and unfolding function is  streigt forward:

```
function folded = foldFeature(alphaLayers, layerColors)
  folded = [alphaLayers(:);layerColors(:)];  
end 


function [alphaLayers, layerColors] = unfoldFeatures(x, rows, columns, dimModel)
  alphaLayersSize = rows*columns*dimModel;
  alphaLayers = reshape(x(1:alphaLayersSize), rows, columns, dimModel);
  layerColors = reshape(x(alphaLayersSize+1:end), rows, columns, 3, dimModel);
end
```

Comment: I don't see your eq-defs. What do you mean after 6 its. At least for interior-point methods (sqp too imho), constraints are only guaranteed to be unviolated at time of convergence! That's the math-core!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the function header. After 6 iterations of the optimization algorithm the costs are going through the roof. But it seems I have to reread the basics. Thanks for your help @sascha